# git local vs remote repository

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I read about git and its behaviour, and I tried a little experiment with tortoise git. Now I'm not sure to really understand the git basics, and specifically on the "places" of workspace/index/localRepo/remoteRepo ...

It is my understanding that a best practice is to separate the workspace from the `localRepository`.

So with tortoiseGit, I create a bare repo "`localRepo.git`".
I also created separated "`workspace`" and "`workspace2`" directories. In each one, I cloned the repo.

At this point, I thought that creating a new file in "`workspace`", and `commit` it should make it appear on the "Repo-browser" of "`localRepo.git`", unfortunately it is not the case...

In fact, I had to do a `push`, to be able to see it in repo-browser, and get it in "`workspace2`" for instance

So here is my problem, I thought the `push` operation's aim was to put my modifications to the remote repository, but here I think that "`localRepo.git`" is my local repository....

Basicaly, I think I don't understand if there is a difference between a local and a remote repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is my understanding that a best practice is to separate the workspace from the localRepository.

Where did you get this idea? Egit from Eclipse encourages this, but I've rarely seen it done elsewhere.

> with tortoiseGit, I create a bare repo "`localRepo.git`". I also created separated "`workspace`" and "`workspace2`" directories. In each one, I cloned the repo.

Cloning a repository creates a new repository. At this point you've got three local repositories: a bare repo `localRepo.git`, and two non-bare repositories in `workspace` and `workspace2`.

Since you cloned your `workspace` and `workspace2` repositories from `localRepo.git`, the default behaviour is for `localRepo.git` to be set as a remote (`origin`) in the other two. You can see your configured remotes with

```
git remote -v
```

This is much more complicated than you need in most situations. Normally a single local repository is plenty.

> At this point, I thought that creating a new file in "`workspace`", and `commit` it should make it appear on the "Repo-browser" of "`localRepo.git`", unfortunately it is not the case

Committing a file in `workspace` commits it to that repository.

> So here is my problem, I thought the `push` operation's aim was to put my modifications to the remote repository, but here I think that "`localRepo.git`" is my local repository

`git push` copies commits to another repository (usually a remote). As we saw above `localRepo.git` is configured as a remote called `origin` for your other two repositories, so `push`ing defaults to sending the commits there.

Comment: I still have another question : where/how is configured the remote (origin) of a repo? (in git definition I mean, I'll figure it out how to find this information in tortoise).
Also, can I conclude from your answer that we could have a 'chain' of repo, saying A is th origin of B which is the origin of C which is...?
Finally, do you know how to link a workspace to a repository?
Indeed if I have a repository on my desktop, I really don't know how to have a separate workspace.

Comment: @GossetEtienne, it might also be a good idea to read a beginner's guide to Git, or a more thorough reference like [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2).

Comment: I totaly agree with you, but my original point was on the difference between local and remote repos, that's why I insist on this point, and also derive on my second 'sub-question'... Anyway you answer was helpful, I'll accept it and ask another one more specific. Thank you for your time. (I read some guide and post about git, I thought combining it with my svn experience would be enough,... It seem it is not the case;-) )

Comment: @GossetEtienne, I understand your frustration. The fact is that there is *very little* that differentiates local and remote repositories. They're fundamentally the same. (It is common—but not required—for remote repositories to be bare, but local repositories can be too.) "Local" and "remote" mean just that: the machine in front of you, or some other machine. Git and Subversion are very different systems, and unfortunately your SVN experience might actually put you at a *dis*advantage. Try to leave everything you learned about SVN behind and approach Git with an open mind.